# How to add sound in custom created boot animation?

Tags: boot, boot-loop, boot-animation

I successfully created a boot animation but I want to add sound to it. How do I do it? 
Unfortunately

> "PowerOn.ogg" in /system/media/ui

did not work.
Any help is appreciated.

```
                                   ##  Thank you! ##
```

Comment: Did your device have a boot sound by default?

Comment: @DanBrown yes I did on my previous rom.  `Stock rom for moto g 2014`.

Comment: If it's still the stock ROM, just make sure the file has the right permission set (I think it's 0440). If the ROM is custom, They've probably removed that 'feature' or moved it elsewhere.

Comment: @DanBrown I'm on a custom rom now. If they removed it then is there any way I can tweak it to get it back working? Thanks!